# Saving information plist

Tags: ios, plist

I'm saving to a plist which I want to later access.  Unfortunately it seems every time I start my app and retreive the plist with the following code, I get a new directory.  Is there a way to make sure NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains always returns the same file path?:

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath;
filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

Comment: Why do you care if the path is different each time? This is normal.

Comment: I want to save a small amount of game data, but without the complexity of NSCoder (found this tutorial, ugh: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data).  I could use NSUserDefaults but I wanted to break up the data into multiple files.  Any advice?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Your question is about the path being different. And I asked you why that mattered. Your code shouldn't care that the path changes. Are you having an issue due to the path changing or are you just curious?

Comment: Well if the path changes then next time I run the app I will end up creating a new plist when I call writeToFile.  I want to access the same plist with the saved data.  Does that clarify a bit better?

Comment: No, when the path changes, iOS will have copied the content of the old path to the new path. Nothing will be lost. You only lose data if you delete the app first.

Comment: hmmm, how strange, but good to know.  I'll check again to make sure I'm getting back different data each time i run it.  That's what I'm pretty sure was happening.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this correctly. Each time an app is installed into the simulator or device, it's placed into a different directory. Your relative path always remains unchanged though!

Comment: aha, I see.  But when placed in a new directory after a new install, would the plist data from the previous install remain (I'm assuming no)?  Also, would this not occur if I simply ran the app without re-installing/building?

Comment: Your data from previous run shall remain intact!